# How to do transition to another screen after google sign in?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, google-signin

I do program and want to do regestration with google sign in. Where do i need to set the enter to another screen?

```
GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(   scopes: [
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',   ], );

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {   @override  
_LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState(); }

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {

  Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
      await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }   }

  @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: ListView(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Form(
                autovalidate: true,
                child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ButtonTheme(
                        minWidth: double.infinity,
                        height: 55.0,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                              side: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.red)),
                          color: Colors.white,
                          onPressed: _handleSignIn
                          //    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home_screen');
                          ,
                          child: Text(
                            'Sign in with Google',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ])),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );   } }
```

if i click on the button should appear google sign in and after adding the account had be enter to another screen.
But when i click on the button, the google sign in opens and after adding the account nothing heppend.

Comment: are you using firebase auth in conjunction with google signin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of Navigator pushReplacement is wrong. Try: `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> HomeScreen()));`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it didn't help.

Comment: did you checked if login was successful or not?

Comment: Thanks for your help, the problem was in SHA1